# Сравнение циклов

Tags: c#, консоль, foreach, if

**Добрый день!**

У меня есть коллекция, в которую вводиться содержимое файла *json*. В файле есть два свойства **hash** и **url**.

И есть два метода, один метод выводит **hash** с этой коллекции,
второй метод берёт **url** с этой коллекции и выводит **hash** с удалённого сервера.
Простым языком, выводиться **hash** с локального файла, и **hash** с сервера (с помощью **url**, который берётся с коллекции).

Мне нужно сравнить эти **hash**-ы (удалённые и локальные) на идентичность.
Но я не могу понять как мне их сравнить.

**Вот код:**

```
class RepoInfo : Process
{
    public Uri url { get; set; }
    public string hash { get; set; }

    public string GetRemoteHashMethod(string url)
    {
        string repourl = Convert.ToString(url);
        var hash = Repository.ListRemoteReferences(repourl).FirstOrDefault() as SymbolicReference;
        return hash.Target.TargetIdentifier;   
    }

    public void PrintLocalHashMethod()
    {
        Process GetHashFromFile = new Process();
        var repos = GetHashFromFile.GetAllFromFile();

        Console.WriteLine("LocalHash:");
        foreach (var item in repos)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.hash);
        }           
    }

    public void PrintRemoteHashMethod()
    {
        Process GetHashFromFile = new Process();
        var repos = GetHashFromFile.GetAllFromFile();

        Console.WriteLine("Remote Hash Commit: ");
        foreach (var item in repos)
        {
            RepoInfo PrintRemoteHash = new RepoInfo();
            var PrintRemoteHashCommit = PrintRemoteHash.GetRemoteHashMethod(item.url.ToString());

            Console.WriteLine(PrintRemoteHashCommit);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}

class Process
{
    public IEnumerable<RepoInfo> GetAllFromFile()
    {
        StreamReader jsonfile = new StreamReader("repo.json");
        string json = jsonfile.ReadToEnd();
        IEnumerable<RepoInfo> repos = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<RepoInfo>>(json);
        return repos;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        RepoInfo PrintRH = new RepoInfo();
        PrintRH.PrintRemoteHashMethod();
        RepoInfo PrintLH = new RepoInfo();
        PrintLH.PrintLocalHashMethod();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

**Сам файл json:**

```
[
  {
    "hash": "2abead42b6a632e29433b043b11d8eec156394b9",
    "url": "https://github.com/VladislavsGeidans/wikicar.git"
  },
  {
    "hash": "bed322e3aa9cbcdeebac7a2d963c2e693a783c2a",
    "url": "https://github.com/OpenExoplanetCatalogue/open_exoplanet_catalogue.git"
  },
  {
    "hash": "0cf7da012e23b64c8aadba49b051542d3d5f47ab",
    "url": "https://github.com/openaddresses/openaddresses.git"
  },
  {
    "hash": "c798444a83795a5f245dc29ccd82872e61206ad5",
    "url": "https://github.com/GSA/data.git"
  },
  {
    "hash": "a45c4cd79a127296acc32aaa8152ebfb49b20640",
    "url": "https://github.com/unitedstates/congress-legislators.git"
  },
  {
    "hash": "e92bc448678ef499cfeabb3df93ea7adad47f747",
    "url": "https://github.com/APIs-guru/openapi-directory.git"
  }
]
```

Comment: Просто совет: в c# обычно используют lowerCamelCase для наименования экземпляров классов и методов. К примеру `RepoInfo printRH = new RepoInfo();` https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase

Comment: @koks_rs Спасибо за совет!:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, явно есть проблемы с архитектурой. 
Методы `PrintLocalHashMethod()` и `PrintRemoteHashMethod()` хорошо бы переписать чтобы они испольвали свой класс, а не создавали экземпляр внутри себя.
Во-вторых, не стоит созадвать экземпляр класса в цикле как вы сделал в функции `PrintRemoteHashMethod`

Ответом на Ваш вопрос будет что-то вроде след фунцкции :

```
    public void Compare()
    {
        IEnumerable<RepoInfo> repos = GetAllFromFile();

        foreach (var item in repos)
        {
            string remoteHash = GetRemoteHashMethod(item.url.ToString());

            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Локальный хэш : {0}, удаленный {1}, совпадают : {2}", item.hash, remoteHash, remoteHash == item.hash));
        }
        Console.WriteLine();

    }
```